# Multiple Tab content with one nav-tab not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created One Nav Tab and Two nav-content but second nav content is showing in first tab content also
 here is sample code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Price</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Activity Details</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4">Upload Photos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Home, Price, Details and Menu 3 having One form so that i have used one tab content for that and Upload Photos have other form with second tab content but second tab content is showing in every first tab content

Comment: Can you show the structure for the actual content of the tabs. It's hard to tell what might be the problem with just the tab navigation.